# Login system that differentiate admin from user

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a login system and I want to distinguish an admin from an user and I have a field in my table which takes a value 0 or 1 to distinguish. The problem is that i don't know how to procede to differentiate the login, so that later I can make some restrictions on buttons.
 How do i make those restrictions also?

```
<?php
//short_open_tag = true;
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 if($_POST)
{

$host="xxxxx"; // Host name 
$username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxxxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxxx"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="utilizador";


// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");


    $tbl_name="utilizador"; // Table name 

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST['username']);
    $encrypted_password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link ,$_POST['password']);
    $sql="SELECT nome FROM $tbl_name WHERE nome='$username' and  pass='$encrypted_password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $encrypted_password1 = md5($encrypted_password);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be *AT LEAST* 1 row
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $username1 = $_SESSION['user']; 

        header("Location: homepage.php");

    }
    else {
        header("Location: index2.php");

        die;
    } 
}
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ''))
 {

    header ("Location: homepage.php");
}


  $link->close();
   ?>
```

Comment: The simple way is to check whether the user is user or admin at the beggining of script (check in the database) and store it in the property, e.q. `$isAdmin=TRUE/FALSE`. Then you could hide/view elements and functionality by condition `if ($isAdmin) {...}`.

Comment: could you please be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Similarly as you have the row where you selects user from DB `$sql="SELECT nome FROM $tbl_name WHERE nome='$username' and  pass='$encrypted_password'";`. But now you have to SELECT the column in which you distinguish the admin and user. Something like this `$sql="SELECT distinguish_column FROM $tbl_name WHERE nome='$_SESSION['user'][0]['nome']' LIMIT 1"`. But first you should prevent the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: in my login i tried to do this :

`$sql1="SELECT Admin FROM utilizador WHERE nome='$username1' LIMIT 1"; $isAdmin=mysqli_query($link, $sql1); if($isAdmin = 1) { $isAdmin = true; } else { $isAdmin = false; }`

and to make the restriction in the other page i did this:

`<?php if($isAdmin = true) { echo "<a href='paginaUtilizador.php'><h2>Admin</h2></a>" } else { echo "no permission"; }; ?>`

Is this the right way to do it? I get an error saying syntax error after the if($isadmin = true), unexpected }.

The syntax maybe wrong but is the logic correct?
thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score -1):

Try to change it like this, not sure if it works but try it:

```
$sql1="SELECT Admin FROM utilizador WHERE nome='$username1' LIMIT 1";
        global $isAdmin;
        $isAdmin=mysqli_query($link, $sql1);

        if($isAdmin = 1) {
            $isAdmin = true;
        }
        else {
            $isAdmin = false;
        }
```

And then to make the if statement:

```
<?php if($isAdmin) : ?>

 <a href='paginaUtilizador.php'><h2>Admin</h2></a>
```

Comment: i've tried and didn't succeed. it returns an undefined variable: isAdmin.... can someone help out?